# How can I manage an oversensitive touchpad?

Tags: xorg, touchpad

For the most part, I love my new Dell Latitude E6510.  However, the touch pad is driving me mad.  It's so sensitive that it will respond to my hands being *near* it, without actually touching it, if they are warm as when I come in from outside or finish doing dishes.  Typing is very difficult because I keep sending the mouse off on unintentional clicks and movements.

I tried disabling the touchpad entirely, but I don't always have a surface to mouse on, and the eraser mouse isn't doing it for me.  I'd like to find a better way to deal with the problem -- possibly by decreasing touchpad sensitivity, having it turn off while typing and back on while not typing, or turning it on/off with a key combination.  I'm open to other ideas, too, if I've overlooked something.

I'm running Funtoo stable.  My WM is XFCE4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a Synaptics touchpad (most are), play with its [options](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.xhtml). You can change options on the fly with the [synclient](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/synclient.1.xhtml) utility.

It looks like you'll want to experiment with the `Synaptics Finger` property, and perhaps other options whose description contains the word “pressure”.

The [Arch Synaptics guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics) looks good and is moslty distribution-agnostic.

Comment: Good answer .. upvote. I also have a request: me and my teammates are working on a web project which is a Q&A website (like SE). But it is in Persian language (because lots of Iranian people don't know English and cannot use SE). We are a (8 members) team and using Asana as our task manager. Our project will be launch in 2 months. I really like to add you to our project and write your name in the about_us page. We really don't expect you to do anything, just be there. It gives us credit. Would you please accept my request?

Comment: Noted that, we never will define task for you, just we probably use your experiences (which rarely happens) and mention to your name as our server-consultant.

Comment: @MartinAJ As it says on every page on this site, the content is licensed under [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). This means two rules. 1. If you use content from me (translated or not), you must say that it's from me. 2. If you modify it, you must make it clear that this isn't what I wrote originally. In other words, you must not claim that I wrote something if I didn't write it. Claiming that I participated in your project would violate rule (2), so no, you may not do that.

Comment: Nice logically proof. Just to make my request more clear, I intended to add you (as a senior) to a group which contains some juniors and cunsolt with you when we really stuck on something or we need to know your idea about something. Also I liked to write your name as our consultant. That's it. Thank you anyway. `:-)`

Comment: @MartinAJ No, I do not do consulting at this time.